# Vue Dynamic Component & Dynamic props

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-props

I have a modal component like below

```html
<modal>
    <component
        :is="modalComponent"
    />
</modal>
```

And I need to pass different props to the dynamic component.

Component A needs a a title, and array of names
Component B needs a a title, array of events and a date as a string.

What is the best way to pass different props to the dynamic component? I don't really want to pass all props to the dynamic components.

```html
<modal>
    <component
        :is="modalComponent"
        :title='title'
        :names='names'
        :events='events'
        :eventDate='eventDate'
    />
</modal>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a computed property to generate the props:

```vue
<component :is="modalComponent" v-bind="props"/>
```

```js
computed: {
  props() {
    if (this.modalComponent === 'ComponentA') {
      return {
        title: this.title,
        names: this.names,
      }
    } else if (this.modalComponent === 'ComponentB') {
      return {
        title: this.title,
        events: this.events,
        eventDate: this.eventDate,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add a `else` to return an empty object. It will handle every component except A and B instead of throwing an error.

Comment: It won't throw an error in that case, `props` will simply be `undefined` and Vue can handle that just fine. In any case, OP didn't mention there were other cases, or what to do in such a situation. It's extra fluff not related to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did see an example like that to be honest I was not too keen on it, just seems a little verbose.